# Kubernetes 1.18 Warning ImageGCFailed Error failed to get imageFs info: unable to find data in memory cache

Tags: docker, kubernetes, garbage-collection, centos7

I brought my Kubernetes 1.18 on Centos 7. We are also using customized CIDR using

kubectl apply -f "https://cloud.weave.works/k8s/net?k8s-version=$(kubectl version | base64 | tr -d '\n')&env.IPALLOC_RANGE=IPALLOC

Initially, Kubernetes came up properly. But when we running the same pod multiple times for testing Kubelet get restarted every 5s.

When I checked,

> Kubectl get events

```
7m43s       Normal    Starting                  node/rajasvm   Starting kubelet.
7m43s       Normal    NodeHasSufficientMemory   node/rajasvm   Node rajasvm status is now: NodeHasSufficientMemory
7m43s       Normal    NodeHasNoDiskPressure     node/rajasvm   Node rajasvm status is now: NodeHasNoDiskPressure
7m43s       Normal    NodeHasSufficientPID      node/rajasvm   Node rajasvm status is now: NodeHasSufficientPID
7m26s       Normal    Starting                  node/rajasvm   Starting kubelet.
7m26s       Normal    NodeHasSufficientMemory   node/rajasvm   Node rajasvm status is now: NodeHasSufficientMemory
7m26s       Normal    NodeHasNoDiskPressure     node/rajasvm   Node rajasvm status is now: NodeHasNoDiskPressure
7m26s       Normal    NodeHasSufficientPID      node/rajasvm   Node rajasvm status is now: NodeHasSufficientPID
7m9s        Normal    Starting                  node/rajasvm   Starting kubelet.
7m9s        Warning   ImageGCFailed             node/rajasvm   failed to get imageFs info: unable to find data in memory cache
6m52s       Normal    Starting                  node/rajasvm   Starting kubelet.
6m35s       Normal    Starting                  node/rajasvm   Starting kubelet.
6m35s       Normal    NodeHasSufficientMemory   node/rajasvm   Node rajasvm status is now: NodeHasSufficientMemory
6m35s       Normal    NodeHasNoDiskPressure     node/rajasvm   Node rajasvm status is now: NodeHasNoDiskPressure
6m35s       Normal    NodeHasSufficientPID      node/rajasvm   Node rajasvm status is now: NodeHasSufficientPID
```

> journalctl -u kubelet | grep -i garbage

```
May 27 17:00:05 rajasvm kubelet[20241]: E0527 17:00:05.374190   20241 kubelet.go:1305] Image garbage collection failed once. Stats initialization may not have completed yet: failed to get imageFs info: unable to find data in memory cache
May 27 17:00:22 rajasvm kubelet[20401]: E0527 17:00:22.152485   20401 kubelet.go:1305] Image garbage collection failed once. Stats initialization may not have completed yet: failed to get imageFs info: unable to find data in memory cache
May 27 17:00:39 rajasvm kubelet[20548]: E0527 17:00:39.141443   20548 kubelet.go:1305] Image garbage collection failed once. Stats initialization may not have completed yet: failed to get imageFs info: unable to find data in memory cache
May 27 17:00:55 rajasvm kubelet[20693]: E0527 17:00:55.953994   20693 kubelet.go:1305] Image garbage collection failed once. Stats initialization may not have completed yet: failed to get imageFs info: unable to find data in memory cache
May 27 17:01:12 rajasvm kubelet[20848]: E0527 17:01:12.668267   20848 kubelet.go:1305] Image garbage collection failed once. Stats initialization may not have completed yet: failed to get imageFs info: unable to find data in memory cache
May 27 17:01:29 rajasvm kubelet[20994]: E0527 17:01:29.676793   20994 kubelet.go:1305] Image garbage collection failed once. Stats initialization may not have completed yet: failed to get imageFs info: unable to find data in memory cache
May 27 17:01:46 rajasvm kubelet[21136]: E0527 17:01:46.367956   21136 kubelet.go:1305] Image garbage collection failed once. Stats initialization may not have completed yet: failed to get imageFs info: unable to find data in memory cache
May 27 17:02:03 rajasvm kubelet[21282]: E0527 17:02:03.181850   21282 kubelet.go:1305] Image garbage collection failed once. Stats initialization may not have completed yet: failed to get imageFs info: unable to find data in memory cache
May 27 17:02:03 rajasvm kubelet[21282]: E0527 17:02:03.181865   21282 kubelet.go:1301] Image garbage collection failed multiple times in a row: failed to get imageFs info: unable to find data in memory cache
```

Please let me know how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 2):

I got the solution, it looks like deleted docker images somehow didn't clean up properly.No idea about this. But below solution worked for me

```
docker system prune
systemctl stop kubelet
systemctl stop docker
systemctl start docker
systemctl start kubelet
```

Comment: What if there is no docker anymore?